# Why Are There Extra Spaces in the MySQL Column That Match the Number of the Characters in the Column?

Tags: mysql

I imported a CSV file into the table `cus` in MySQL.
These are my columns:

```
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| seqNum | smallint     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bbRef  | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bkName | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| chNum  | tinyint      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vsNum  | tinyint      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vsTxt  | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

In the `Terminal.app` on Mac, when I read from the table by using `SELECT * FROM cus WHERE seqNum=<a number>;`, I get some unexpected results: In the `vsTxt` column, **each string is followed by a number of the characters in the string.**

For instance, in the first case in the screenshot below, when the string contains **8 characters** (the string is **preceded by a space**, so 9 in total), there are **9 spaces** (highlighted part in the screenshot) following it.

In the second case, there are **14 characters** **preceded by one space**, then there are **15 spaces** that follow it.

In the third case, there are **46 characters preceded by one space**, then there are **47 spaces** following it.

[image]

Is it something expected? I don't want those extra spaces displayed. (One space between the strong and column marker is fine.)

I tried to trim the column by using

```
mysql> update cus set vsTxt =  trim(replace(vsTxt, ' ', ''));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 31219  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Nothing is affected, and I'm still getting these spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL command-line table column width with utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128302/mysql-command-line-table-column-width-with-utf8)

Comment: *Changed: 0* There is no spaces in the values. Check `CHAR_LENGTH(vsTxt)` and `LENGTH(vsTxt)` values. Either this is client isssue or these symbols are not spaces.

Comment: I'm guessing they aren't ASCII spaces. There are some unicode characters that are "invisible" and appear the same as a space, but they are actually [different characters](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs). I tested one (the En Space), and confirmed that MySQL's TRIM() function does not strip it.

Comment: Hi @Akina, I checked these two commands. With a returned column as this: `| 愿主耶稣的恩惠，常与众圣徒同在。阿们。                    |` (the `|` sign is the column border), I get `19` and `57` respectively. I assume `19` represents the character length of the string, which has 19 characters. This is followed by 19 spaces. There is one extra space next to the column border. Therefore, the output is `|`,`one space`,`19 characters`, `19 spaces`, `one space`, `|`.

Comment: Please look at these functions description in Manual Reference... "19 spaces" printed in CLI are not column value chars...

Comment: Hi @Progman, the post you linked seems to describe the same issue. So there is no solution to it if I use utf8?

Comment: Thanks, @Akina. I know very little about CLI. "Space" is the best word I could find to describe the issue. ️